# How to pass props to redux store from a Rails 5 views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, redux, react-on-rails

I cannot seem to understand the [docs](https://github.com/shakacode/react_on_rails#redux_store) on how to pass props from views to redux store.

**Registration.jsx**

```
import configureStore from '../store/configureStore';

ReactOnRails.registerStore({
  configureStore,
});

// This is how react_on_rails can see the HelloWorld in the browser.   
[...]
```

**Views:**

```
<%= redux_store('configureStore', props: { profile: current_user.profile }) %>
<%= react_component 'NewProjectApp' %>
```

Im now lost. I thought in my react component I could do `{props.profile}`.

My app will have multiple components that will connect one store. Do I need to create a reducer just to gain access to the profile prop?

**Reducer:**

```
[...]
const profile = (profile) => {
  console.log(profile)
  return " "
};

// exporting the combined reducers
// shorten:
// combineReducers({ profile });

[...]
```

The weird part, in my console, I see `undefined` two times then on the third. I see the profile object. Huh? Im still learning how redux works by changing up the default `HelloWorlApp` example that react on rails gives.